# Can TransactionTemplate be used with multiple data sources in Grails?

Tags: grails, transactions, grails-orm, multi-tenant

In our Grails application, we use one database per tenant. Each database contains data of all domain objects. We switch the databases based on the request context using pattern like `DomainClass.getDS().find()`.

The transactions do not work out of the box since the request does not know what transaction manager to use. The `@Transactional` and `withTransaction` do nothing.

I have implemented my own version of withTransaction():

```
public static def withTransaction(Closure callable) {
    new TransactionTemplate(getTM()).execute(callable as TransactionCallback)
}
```

The getTM() returns transaction manager based of the request context, for example `transactionManager_db0`.

This seems to work in my sandbox. Will this also work:

- For parallel requests?
- If the database has several replicas?
- For hierarchical transactions?

I believe in TDD, but with the exception of the last bullet, I have hard times to provide tests to verify the code.